# Mysql helm chart not working when we delete existing helm chart and try installing again

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have added stable/mysql chart in requirements.yaml

```
dependencies:
  - name: mysql
    version: 1.4.0
    repository: https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com
    condition: global.install_mysql
```

Created a PVC

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mysql-azure-managed-disk
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: managed-premium
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
```

And added persistence in mycharts values.yaml

```
mysql:
  persistence:
    enabled: false
    storageClass: managed-premium
    existingClaim: mysql-azure-managed-disk
    accessMode: ReadWriteOnce
    size: 1Gi
    annotations: {}
```

When I install mychart `helm install --name mychart .` the chart gets installed successfully and my other pod is also able to connect to the mysql pod with password from secrets.

But when I delete the chart and install again new pod is not able to connect to the mysql pod.

Has anyone faces this issue?

This is the first time log

```
C02XF0N6JG5M:mychart komal$ k logs -f mychart-mysql-6f5f77445f-d2sld 
Initializing database
Database initialized
MySQL init process in progress...
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/Factory' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/iso3166.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/leap-seconds.list' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/posix/Factory' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/right/Factory' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.


MySQL init process done. Ready for start up.
```

Secrets created for first time

```
k get secrets mychart-mysql -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
data:
  mysql-password: dmY3NjIybU9FTA==
  mysql-root-password: WWRCVHo4MDFNcQ==
kind: Secret
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2020-03-06T07:51:01Z"
  labels:
    app: mychart-mysql
    chart: mysql-1.4.0
    heritage: Tiller
    release: reancore
  name: reancore-mysql
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "2450905"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/secrets/reancore-mysql
  uid: a1ec1f81-8986-4aad-b952-af2dad1fab5a
type: Opaque
```

When I am trying to get thee logs second time, it doesn't give me anything in logs, but the pod is started and running.

This is the describe output

```
k describe pods mychart-mysql-6f5f77445f-fv4rj
Name:           mychart-mysql-6f5f77445f-fv4rj
Namespace:      default
Priority:       0
Node:           aks-agentpool-16017342-vmss000000/10.240.0.4
Start Time:     Fri, 06 Mar 2020 14:09:12 +0530
Labels:         app=mychart-mysql
                pod-template-hash=6f5f77445f
                release=mychart
Annotations:    <none>
Status:         Running
IP:             10.244.0.139
IPs:            <none>
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/mychart-mysql-6f5f77445f
Init Containers:
  remove-lost-found:
    Container ID:  docker://e8791c6acbac6ac6a37c0e9bf039015a84330feee5a4ad52e98ca530b71df804
    Image:         busybox:1.29.3
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://busybox@sha256:8ccbac733d19c0dd4d70b4f0c1e12245b5fa3ad24758a11035ee505c629c0796
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    Command:
      rm
      -fr
      /var/lib/mysql/lost+found
    State:          Terminated
      Reason:       Completed
      Exit Code:    0
      Started:      Fri, 06 Mar 2020 14:09:34 +0530
      Finished:     Fri, 06 Mar 2020 14:09:34 +0530
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Requests:
      cpu:        10m
      memory:     10Mi
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/lib/mysql from data (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-gdgms (ro)
Containers:
  mychart-mysql:
    Container ID:   docker://54e5dc22543fcc028ab000eda1fe08569ed65b31c2072b74068eb861eb4ce119
    Image:          mysql:5.7.14
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://mysql@sha256:c8f03238ca1783d25af320877f063a36dbfce0daa56a7b4955e6c6e05ab5c70b
    Port:           3306/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Running
      Started:      Fri, 06 Mar 2020 14:09:34 +0530
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Requests:
      cpu:      100m
      memory:   256Mi
    Liveness:   exec [sh -c mysqladmin ping -u root -p${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}] delay=30s timeout=5s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Readiness:  exec [sh -c mysqladmin ping -u root -p${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}] delay=5s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD:  <set to the key 'mysql-root-password' in secret 'mychart-mysql'>  Optional: false
      MYSQL_PASSWORD:       <set to the key 'mysql-password' in secret 'mychart-mysql'>       Optional: true
      MYSQL_USER:           
      MYSQL_DATABASE:       
    Mounts:
      /var/lib/mysql from data (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-gdgms (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             True 
  ContainersReady   True 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  data:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  mysql-azure-managed-disk2
    ReadOnly:   false
  default-token-gdgms:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-gdgms
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       Burstable
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type    Reason     Age    From                                        Message
  ----    ------     ----   ----                                        -------
  Normal  Scheduled  3m4s   default-scheduler                           Successfully assigned default/mychart-mysql-6f5f77445f-fv4rj to aks-agentpool-16017342-vmss000000
  Normal  Pulled     2m43s  kubelet, aks-agentpool-16017342-vmss000000  Container image "busybox:1.29.3" already present on machine
  Normal  Created    2m43s  kubelet, aks-agentpool-16017342-vmss000000  Created container remove-lost-found
  Normal  Started    2m42s  kubelet, aks-agentpool-16017342-vmss000000  Started container remove-lost-found
  Normal  Pulled     2m42s  kubelet, aks-agentpool-16017342-vmss000000  Container image "mysql:5.7.14" already present on machine
  Normal  Created    2m42s  kubelet, aks-agentpool-16017342-vmss000000  Created container mychart-mysql
  Normal  Started    2m41s  kubelet, aks-agentpool-16017342-vmss000000  Started container mychart-mysql
```

Somehow second time my applications pod is not able to connect to the mysql's pod

Comment: Please post the logs of the MySQL pod on the second install. 
My guess is that the chart is automatically creating a secret which is not tracked by Helm. so when you delete the helm deployment the secret is still there, the next time it uses this old secret.  So you will see in the logs: authentication failing.

Comment: @NicoKowe Sorry for the delay, I have updated my question with the logs

Answer (score 1):

When I add mysqlRootPassword in values.yaml, even when I delete the chart and install new again. It connects to mysql pod every time.

```
mysql:
  mysqlRootPassword: root1
  persistence:
    enabled: false
    storageClass: managed-premium
    existingClaim: mysql-azure-managed-disk
    accessMode: ReadWriteOnce
    size: 1Gi
    annotations: {}
```